# How to convert PFGeoPoint to CLLocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, cllocationmanager

Is it possible to convert the PFGeoPoint with Parse to a CLLocation?

Reason being I'm trying to get the names of places from PFGeoPoint like so:

```
   CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
     PFGeoPoint *point = [object objectForKey:@"location"];
                            [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:point completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                                NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
                                if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
                                {
                                    placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
                                    NSLog(@"%@", placemarks);

                                }
                            }];
```

Error I get obviously is:

```
Incompatiable pointer types sending 'PFGeoPoint *' to parameter of type 'CLLocation *'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly create the `CLLocation` instance using `initWithLatitude:longitude:` with the `latitude` and `longitude` from the `PFGeoPoint`. There is only a convenience method for creating a `PFGeoPoint` from a `CLLocation`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 6):

As Wain said there is no convenient method to convert from `PFGeoPoint` to a `CLLocation` however you can make your own and extend `PFGeoPoint` using the following

```
import Parse

extension PFGeoPoint {

    func location() -> CLLocation {
        return CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
    }
}
```

now you can easily return a CLLocation object by doing

```
let aLocation: CLLocation = yourGeoPointObject.location()
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Justin Oroz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310011/1387646) (see the answer below):
Also a great idea could be to create the extension in the CLLocation side so it can be created using a convenience init which receives the PFGeoPoint:

```
extension CLLocation {
    convenience init(geoPoint: PFGeoPoint) {
        self.init(latitude: geoPoint.latitude, longitude: geoPoint.longitude)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always get the PFGeoPoint and then add it to a CLLocationCoordinate2D like this:

```
//get all PFObjects

let parseLocation = ParseObject["location"]

let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: parseLocation.latitude, longitude: parseLocation.longitude)
```